# String Manipulation to remove Change lines in a string

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

**Given** : I have a SQL Script with comments.

**Requirement** : To parse the comments and sql queries separately and -

1. Store Comments & also remove (--) [FACING PROBLEM IN THIS STEP]
2. Run the respective Queries  [ ALREADY IMPLEMENTED ]
3. Store the Comments and respective Queries results.

I have already Tried -

1. regex ( i.e re.sub )
2. String Manipulation to remove line change like - 
   `string.replace('\n','<br />')` & `string=<br />.join(string.split("\n")`

#### Code Snippet

```
    def executescript(filename,redshift_cursor):
        fd = open(filename,'r')
        sqlFile=fd.read()
        fd.close()
        sqlcommands=sqlFile.split(';')
        cur=redshift_cursor

        for commands in sqlcommands:
            try:
                #ATTEMPT WITH REGEX - 
                processed_comment = re.sub('--', "", re.sub('(\?|\.).+?(SELECT)(.*)', "", commands))
                print processed_comment
                #ATTEMPT WITH string.replace
                new_comment = commands.replace('\n', '<br />')
                #ATTEMPT WITH "<br />".join(string.split("\n")
                new_comment1 = "<br />".join(commands.split("\n"))
```

ORIGINAL SQL SCRIPT THAT IS BEING PARSED FOR BOTH COMMENTS AND SQL QUERIES -

```
--;
--1 QUERY FOR XVY?
SELECT * from XVZ limit 10;
--2 QUERY FOR PQR.
SELECT * from PQR limit 10;
```

### CURRENT CODE RESULTS -

#### ATTEMPT WITH REGEX RESULTS

```
1 QUERY FOR XVY?
SELECT * from XVZ limit 10;
2 QUERY FOR PQR.
SELECT * from PQR limit 10;
```

#### ATTEMPT WITH string.replace RESULTS IN -

```
--
<br/>SELECT * from XVZ limit 10;
<br/>SELECT * from PQR limit 10;
<br/>
```

#### ATTEMPT WITH string=
.join(string.split("\n")

```
--
<br/>SELECT * from XVZ limit 10;
<br/>SELECT * from PQR limit 10;
<br/>
```

### REQUIRED/EXPECTED RESULT -

```
1 QUERY FOR XVY?

2 QUERY FOR PQR.
```

Comment: I'd use something like https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/ to extract the queries from a file. A query may span across several lines and there may be several queries in one line.

Comment: What against using a if statement and then replace? Like `if "QUERY" in command:` and then `command.replace('-', '')`

Comment: @albo, Actually there is no issue with queries or Parsing the comments. While parsing the comments using the 3 ways ( regex, string.replace, _.join(string.split()), I am not able to filter out the Query to just have the comments.

Comment: The comments you mean is the expected result you provide in your question? Like: `1 QUERY FOR XVY?

2 QUERY FOR PQR.`?

Comment: @Albo, Correct.

Comment: @eumiro, Thanks for the quick response. But the Requirement 2 i.e executing queries has already been implemented by, the problem thats arising related to parsing the Comments in the SQL Script. Please go through the CURRENT CODE RESULTS section of my question which will help you better understand the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

By using simple `if "QUERY" in command` you can check for your required result:

```
sqlcommands = ['--', 
'\r\n--1 QUERY FOR XVY?\r\nSELECT * from XVZ limit 10', 
'\r\n--2 QUERY FOR PQR.\r\nSELECT * from PQR limit 10', 
'\r\n']

sqlcommands = [a for sub in [x.split('\r\n') for x in sqlcommands] for a in sub if a] # flattens the list of lists and checks if the list is empty

comment = []

for command in sqlcommands:
    if "QUERY" in command:
        print(command.replace('-', ''))
    if "SELECT" in command:
        comment.append(command.replace('-', ''))
```

outputs

```
1 QUERY FOR XVY?
2 QUERY FOR PQR.
```

Comment: Thanks Albo,
The sqlcommands is actually a list of strings, in this case it is like - 

['--', '\r\n--1 QUERY FOR XVY?\r\nSELECT * from XVZ limit 10', '\r\n--2 QUERY FOR PQR.\r\nSELECT * from PQR limit 10', '\r\n']

So what I am trying to say is, 
--1 QUERY FOR XVY?
SELECT * from XVZ limit 10;

is a single string stored in the list sqlcommands as --> \r\n--1 QUERY FOR XVY?\r\nSELECT * from XVZ limit 10
Should we get rid of everything after **\r\n** the comes in between the comment and the query by regex or split? 
Besides the above, the comments dont always  start with --n QUERY FOR

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment, please check if this is doing the trick

Comment: Thanks @Albo, Your code did work, but it did create some other issues with other parts of my code. So I used regex like - flattend_comment = re.sub(r'\r\n', '', comment)  and it worked like a charm. Thanks Again :)